# reading characters from file

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having trouble understanding why my code isn't working properly.Just to test it, I have only five characters in my txt file. I know that characters are being put into array I create, but I am not sure why wouldnt it print them. Thanks!

```
        catch (IOException exception) {
            System.err.println(exception);
        }// catch

        finally {
            try {
                if (fileInput != null)
                    fileInput.close();
            }// try

            catch (IOException exception) {
                System.err.println("error!" + exception);
            }// catch

        }// finally

    }// main
}// TestCode
```

Comment: What purpose does `convert` serve, if all it does is return `char`, and you're passing in an element of a `char` array?

Comment: there is //code// ...........means there is lots of code there, but for saving space i just put retun c

Comment: It is better to use junit or similar to write test code.

Comment: Use a debugger, and step through the code.

Comment: Well, I thought there is some serious problem with my constructor, thats' why I wanted experienced programs to maybe spot it, apparently it is not....

Comment: I guess your code is lost (not sure if that is due to my edit. Please post formatted code )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a for loop inside your while reader loop. Better to use:

```
    int index = 0;
    while ((character = fileInput.read()) != -1) {
        inputArray[index] = (char) character;
        index++;
    }
```

Also ensure that you dont exceed the inputArray size. You may want to consider a using a List type if this data is required to grow.

Comment: i'm just testing it for now, i have precisely 5 charcters in file

Comment: well,right now, program exists right after the while loop it never gets the chance to create instance, i dont know why